# No reverse match django class based views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I m new to Django and I am learning it through a project but m stuck with this error which says that NoReverseMatch at /product/create/

here is my **models.py** file

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             related_name='category_created')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             related_name='product_created', null= True,blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    negiotiable = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    users_like = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                        related_name='product_liked',
                                        blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('products_detail',
                       args=[self.slug])
```

This is my **views.py** but I m not sure if there is something wrong with my views

```
from django.views.generic import *
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from .models import Category, Product

class CategoryList(ListView):
    model = Category

class CategoryDetail(DetailView):
    model = Category

class ProductList(ListView):
    model = Product

class ProductDetail(DetailView):
    model = Product

class ProductCreate(CreateView):
    model = Product
    fields = ["category", 'name', 'image', 'description', 'price', 'stock','available', 'negiotiable']

class ProductUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Product
    fields = ['name', 'image', 'description', 'price', 'stock','available', 'negiotiable']

class ProductDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Product
    success_url = reverse_lazy('product_list')
```

Comment: Post _full error message with traceback_ *and* _your template code_ please.

Comment: Could you add your urls.py as well?

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell if this is the problem without the traceback or urls.py but I'm guessing you need to auto-generate the slug field by overriding the save method in the Product model. Instructions here: http://fazle.me/auto-generating-unique-slug-in-django/

Or you could try this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             related_name='product_created', null= True,blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    negiotiable = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    users_like = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                        related_name='product_liked',
                                        blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('products_detail', args=[self.slug])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that this way you will have to change `db_index` to `unique` for the name field.